# Is it possible to share the WiFi of a Mac through Ethernet and go through a proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to make my iPhone's traffic go through Burp Suite. Unfortunately, there are some apps that don't work if a proxy is configured (the easiest way with Burp Suite ist to configure the IP of the Mac as proxy) and simply won't connect.

So I though I'd share my Wifi via Ethernet and setup Burp Suite as the proxy for http and https traffic on the Ethernet connection. I can see that all traffic goes through Burp Suite as long as I use Ethernet, however the shared Wifi ignores the configured Burp Suite proxy.

Since Wifi is shared through Ethernet, I would have imagined that *all* traffic goes through the proxy.

Comment: Just to be clear, how does your Mac get to the Internet? Via Wi-Fi or via Ethernet?

Comment: Via Ethernet. The WiFi connection gets shared.

Comment: Okay, that's why I asked. OS X (at least in English) says it the other way around. If your Internet connection is via Ethernet, it says you're sharing your connection from Ethernet to computers using Wi-Fi. I got confused when you said things the other way around.